# Transformed variable interpretation

Tags: normal-distribution, normalization, normality-assumption

In the analysis of my data, the dependent variable was non normally distributed. I used the two-steps approach by Templeton to transform the variable, and the normality was met.

**NOW:** In the interpretation the results and reporting the descriptive results, which variable I should use (I mean the original one or the transformed one?)? And for the binary logistic regression, I need to create two categories. So, should I use the original variable or transformed variable to obtain the two categories for the logistic regression?

Thank you for each try to help.

Answer (score 1):

if you have conducted the analysis by the use of the transformed variable, then, for clarity and rigorousness, report the results (numbers) with the transformed one (you can’t do anything else if you have used the transformed one for the calculus and this is the approach that I have personally seen in literature, when either the dependent or independent variables are transformed). Then the reader will clearly understand that if the transformation is a simple normalization (which in this case preserves at least the ordinal rank of the observations) then some of the results (like the sign of the relationship if we are in a linear model) will be intuitively extendable to the non-transformed variable backing the transformed one.

But if your only purpose is to draw a logistic regression on that dependent variable, then, for the logistic per se you don’t need to normalize the dependent variable because it will just be re-expressed as 0-1 so you do not need a normal variable before the transformation into 0 and 1.